# Why does my string to float-conversion not get all decimals with istringstream?

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, data-conversion

I am reading a delimiter-separated file line by line and splitting the input by the delimiter '|' thats used in the file. While reading the line I need to convert a input like "1.9" or "2.38" to a float, but I cant seem to make it work. All i get is the first number like "1" or "2.".

What's wrong with my code? My Struct `person` looks like this:

```
struct person {
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    string signature;
    float length;

    string getFullName() {
        return firstname + " " + lastname;
    }
};
```

My Method:

```
vector<person> LoadFromFile(string filename) {
    string line;
    vector<person> listToAddTo;
    person newPerson;

    ifstream infile(filename);
    if (!infile) {
        cerr << "Error opening file." << endl;
        //Error
    }

    while (getline(infile, line)) {
        string field;
        vector<string> fields;
        istringstream iss_line(line);
        while (getline(iss_line, field, DELIM)) {
            fields.push_back(field);
        }

        newPerson.firstname = fields[0];
        newPerson.lastname = fields[1];
        newPerson.length = strtof((fields[2]).c_str(),0);
        newPerson.signature = fields[3];

        listToAddTo.push_back(newPerson);
   }
return listToAddTo;
}
```

And the textfile:

```
morre|bo|1.8|morbox1|
mo|her|1.8|moxher1|
mo|herm|1.9|moxher2|
```

I tried isolating the problem by writing the input to a string, which displays the results just fine.
So the problem seems to be with the conversion from string to float:

```
newPerson.length = strtof((fields[2]).c_str(),0);
```

Comment: If the problem is with converting a string to a float, I recommend creating a [mcve] that doesn't have any of the irrelevant file stuff. Hardcode a string, convert it to a float, and show that the received float is not what you expect.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Have you inspected the content of `fields`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Make sure your example is in fact minimal and complete.

Comment: You haven't set a locale in which the decimal-point character isn't `.`, haven't you? BTW, having tagged this question as C++11, you should look at [std::stof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof).

Comment: [cannot reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bITNrA5Tbuq50Lf7)

Comment: @Bob__ how you caught that is beyond me, but yes, I have a locale in Swedish which sets the decimal-point to ",". I changed to english and and its working fine. I guess I stared at this too long. Thanks a bunch for helping out guys, saved me from loosing more hair! :-)

Comment: @Bob__ You should turn that into an answer.

Comment: Yes please do and I will accept as answer.

Comment: @klasmack Don't forget to provide a [MCVE] in your question please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the documentation about [`std::strtof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) at cpp.reference we can find that

> ... it takes as many characters as possible to form a valid floating-point representation and converts them to a floating-point value...

Where "a valid floating-point representation" can be a

> ... nonempty sequence of decimal digits optionally containing decimal-point character (**as determined by the current C locale**) (defines significand)

Apparently, in OP's locale the decimal-point character was not a `.`, like in the file they were trying to read, so the numbers were misinterpreted.

It's worth noting that, since C++11, we can convert a `std::string` into a number directly, using [`std::stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) instead.